Cloudflare Email worker - no message body
I'm trying to write an auto-reply email worker. the email sends fine, has a subject and the correct from/to. However the message body is always empty. Here's my code (data redacted):
import { EmailMessage } from "cloudflare:email";
import { createMimeMessage } from "mimetext";

export default {
     async email(message, env, ctx) {

    const msg = createMimeMessage();
    msg.setHeader("In-Reply-To", message.headers.get("Message-ID"));
    msg.setSender({ name: "Me", addr: "email@email.com" });
    msg.setRecipient(message.from);
    msg.setSubject("Auto-reply");
    msg.addMessage({
      contentType: 'text/html',
      data: "This is an <b>auto-reply</b>"
    });

    const replyMessage = new EmailMessage(
      "email@email.com",
      message.from,
      msg.asRaw()
    );

    await message.reply(replyMessage);
    }
}

I have also tried setting the message directly:
replyMessage.message = {contentType : "text/html", data:"This is an <b>auto-reply</b>"};

Using
contentType = "text/plain"

didn't work either.

The code is working for me, please try it:
msg.addMessage({
  contentType: 'text/html',
  data: `This is an <b>auto-reply</b>` // changed " to `
});

I simply changed " to ` and the code is working fine.

